# Maintaining entity row version/history manually in database table using JPA/hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa

I don't know where to ask this question or how to ask. Basically what I need that I have  couple of entity classes and if I think in terms of database table , each row will have a specific column like 'S0' which will indicate the current state of the application.My application will fetch data based on 'S0' by default from all the tables(where history='S0' by default).

When I need a history , I fetch all rows where history column = 'S0' and insert new row with value ='S1' having other properties exactly same (except the identity as it changes while inserting). Next time like 'S2' like so on. The S0 rows will remain the same.

My application should have the option to load/populate  itself by selecting archived data. like load app with history S1

How Do I manage this with JPA+Hibernate. in JDBC+JSP I used to have a column history on each table and handle this manually:copy and insert all. But it is a hazard and not good practice I think.

Please help me by giving me some advice /help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you check envers? http://www.jboss.org/envers

Comment: Does envers can be controlled like keep audited only on given instruction to do instead of every time the entity updates?

Comment: My application should have the option to load/populate  itself by selecting archived data. like load app with history S1.